# Flutter Stepper - BoxConstraints forces an infinite width

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I trying to create Stepper, This is my code and I took it copy paste from [flutter doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html):

```
class AdFormView extends GetView<AdFormController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Stepper'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _index = 0;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 300,
      width: 300,
      child: Stepper(
        currentStep: _index,
        onStepCancel: () {
          if (_index <= 0) {
            return;
          }
          setState(() {
            _index--;
          });
        },
        onStepContinue: () {
          if (_index >= 1) {
            return;
          }
          setState(() {
            _index++;
          });
        },
        onStepTapped: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _index = index;
          });
        },
        steps: [
          Step(
            title: Text("Step 1 title"),
            content: Container(
                height: 400,
                width: 400,
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text("Content for Step 1")),
          ),
          Step(
            title: Text("Step 2 title"),
            content: Container(
              height: 400,
              width: 400,
              child: Text("Content for Step 2"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But I got this Error:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
Stepper

The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderConstrainedBox#79f3a relayoutBoundary=up19 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
RenderObject: RenderConstrainedBox#79f3a relayoutBoundary=up19 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=48.0)
    size: MISSING
    additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
    child: RenderPhysicalShape#0b08e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        needs compositing
        parentData: <none>
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
        elevation: 0.0
        color: Color(0xff002c7f)
        shadowColor: Color(0xff002c7f)
        clipper: ShapeBorderClipper
        child: RenderCustomPaint#df4fd NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
            parentData: <none>
            constraints: MISSING
            size: MISSING
            child: _RenderInkFeatures#570e6 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                parentData: <none>
                constraints: MISSING
                size: MISSING
                child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#f05ee NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                    parentData: <none>
                    constraints: MISSING
                    size: MISSING
```

The parent have size, so why It's shows MISSING?
I tried to add max and min width and height and I tried to wrap It in Flexible but nothing works!

I created a new project for test the Stepper,
I created one normal flutter and one with GetX
and they works fine.

I don't know why It's not works in my project, I took the code copy paste, I don't know why it's can't read the size of the parent, I added max width, min width, max height, min height, width and height and not working.

So It's not working only in my project like the image below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: If it works in a brand new getx project, then there is something in your project that is wrong. I assume you've cleaned the cache, done a flutter clean, packages get, rebuild etc. If yes, and still fails, copy all your files (and changes to manifest files, ios plist file etc), to the new project and see if it then works.

Also, you don't mention flutter version, getx version, if it's ios/web/macos etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such error on `MyStatefulWidget`  you can rebuild the project using `flutter clean` then run. this problem can be cause by parent level.